# Need help allocating a far pointer on Borland C++ 3.0

Tags: c, memory, pointers, dos

I am writing a DOS game framework to learn C better and a general interest in programming on old hardware (especially on the system I grew up with).

I am trying to implement a double buffer system but I am having trouble allocating a far pointer to a 320*200 array.

At first I was trying to use malloc but found out it can only allocate under 64kb. I read that you need to use farmalloc (malloc returns NULL) and it allocated correctly. However, when _fmemset or _fmemcpy is run.... the whole system freezes.

```
backBuffer = (unsigned char far*) farmalloc(64000);
```

when it is time to swap buffers I use

```
_fmemcpy(VGA, backBuffer, 64000);
```

Program is using the small memory model.

Comment: What are `VGA`, its value, `backbuffer` and `_fmemcpy()`?

Comment: VGA is a unsigned char far pointer to address 0xA000000L, the address of the VGA memory. Backbuffer is also a unsigned char far pointer, and was allocated with the above function.

Comment: I don't understand 0xA000000L. It must be: segment=0xA000 & offset=0 (that corresponds to physical address = segment * 0x10 + offset = 0xA0000 = 640K). Does it really have segment=0xA000 & offset=0? Or is it segment=0xA00 & offset=0 or something else? The proper way of making such a pointer is via `MK_FP(0xA000, 0)`.

Comment: @loncannon, perhaps it's a typo in your comment, but you're missing a zero, it should be 0xA0000000L.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Very interesting post, I'm also very fond of old hardware.

- **Have you tried compiling in medium or large models to check if the code runs correctly?**
- **Are you sure the pointer to the VGA display memory is correctly initialized?**

I remember that in those days, using a memory copy to swap screen buffers was painfully slow, not to mention that you had to wait for the vertical retrace period to begin copying memory. (I had a bare bones VGA card, so perhaps your hardware is better and the delay is more than acceptable).

If your are interested, I'd strongly advice you to read Michael Abrash's [Mode-X](http://www.phatcode.net/res/224/files/html/ch47/47-01.html#Heading1) columns.

Mode-X and its derivatives are alternative graphic modes first documented by Michael Abrash. Basically they were hacks to the 256 color 13H mode that you could activate by tweaking some registers in the VGA card.

Once activated, there were two great advantages:

1. Four pages of display memory
2. Square Pixels (In original ModeX that is 320x240), (a plotted circle will look like a circle, not an ellipse)

**Implementing a double or even triple buffer was a breeze, as you could directly write to the inactive buffer and activating it simply involved changing a register in the vga card, no memcopy at all!** (you still need to wait for vertical retrace, otherwise there's an ugly flicker)

The disadvantage is that this mode is harder to program,  basically, with mode-X now a single memory address is mapped to four consecutive pixels, so, a single pixel write will actually alter four pixels at once. (this is great acceleration for polygon filler routines!).

If you want to alter a single pixel, then you have to setup a "pixel mask" (also a VGA card register) specifying which of the four pixels will be affected by the memory write, just before you plot the pixel.

This is slow if done naively, as every pixel plotted requires setting up a mask. Usually we intuitively tend to draw things left to right, top to bottom (because that's precisely how video memory is mapped on the VGA mode 13H), but us Mode-X programmers learned it is much faster to "rotate the paradigm", that is, we drew things top-to-bottom, left-to-right.

Why? because this allows us to modify the pixel mask just once for every column drawn!
Here's some pseudocode:

**Naive, intuitive programming**

```
pixelptr = start of screen memory
foreach row
   foreach column
      adjust pixel mask
      write pixel value
      pixelptr+= 1      // advance pointer to next pixel to the left
   next
next
```

**Rotated mode of programming**

[Edit1: added the missing step where pointer must be moved to top of next column]

[Edit2: correction, I was adding 320 to advance to the next row when in fact this should be divided by 4 since a consecutive increment of the video memory address will map to the group of next four pixels to the right of the previous, four-pixel group]

```
for each column
   pixelptr = start of screen memory + current column index
   adjust pixel mask       // same mask applies to every pixel in the same column!
   for each row
      write pixel value
      pixelptr += (320 / 4)  // advance pointer to next pixel, to the bottom
   next
next
```

All the involved steps and register addresses are detailed in the link to the Michael Abrash columns I provided.  This is ancient stuff, but I bet you'll find it fascinating!

Cheers!

Comment: Seems someone closed my question :(. Anyway, this seems to be the "unchained mode" I read about yes? To answer your questions: Medium mode was tried and it would behave strangely when it exited an inline assembly block. VGA display memory is initialized because I had the program drawing before I tackled the back buffer.

Comment: Yes! they refer to the same mode. It was apparently "discovered" simultaneously by several developers, as the mode's existance was hinted, but not detailed, on the VGA technical documentation.  I don't have BC++ 3.0, could you check if there's a compact model available and try it?  It should be 64KB code (just like small mode) but 64+ KB data (maybe the assembly block is assuming a single segment, 64KB of code?) - If you could get hold of a copy of Watcom's C compiler, then you could program in a simpler, flat memory model (no segments) and address all available memory by using protected mode.

Comment: Strange, setting it to compact memory model causes fread to freeze. It seems random spots in the program freeze depending which model I choose. So frustrating.

Comment: Hi @loncannon, sorry to hear that, I was out on a trip.  From what you are describing sounds like you could be having some memory corruption problem (maybe a buffer overrun on some other part of the system). A tool like Numega's BoundsChecker was very helpful for finding these bug spots.

Comment: Another possibility, if you are debugging  under a modern system, are timing issues.  I remember some libraries synchronized things by measuring how fast a computer was, and adjusted delays according to that speed, however today's computers are so fast that on many ocassions the counters are overflowed and give the wrong timing resluts.  Many old games crash because of this. Just dropping some ideas.

Comment: Welcome back. I am running the application in DOS-BOX which does a 100% emulation of MS-DOS. I figured out why my _fmemset and other _fmem functions were not working. They take size_t for the size argument unlike farmalloc takes a long. Having trouble finding a copy of boundchecker. Seems most of my far stuff is working, allocation, freeing, and modifying, however fread() causes the program to halt when loading into a normal unsigned char * allocated with malloc. fopen and fseek work.

Comment: Will do a check if that malloced buffer for fread actually returned null not a ptr.

Comment: It seems I have been able to fix the problem... I didn't include <mem.h> in the certain .c file. I am not sure how it compiled earlier without it, but when included, the function no longer crashed.

Comment: Weird! Don't know how it managed to compile too =) Glad to hear the problem is resolved and you can continue. Would love to hear about your progress.  =)